# how to read multiple variables values inside html tag in python

Tags: python, html

we have below html code which calls in python with one varibale

```
html123='''
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 300px;
  border: 15px solid green;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Demonstrating the Box Model</h2>

<div>This text is $Var1</div>

</body>
</html>
</html>   '''
```

for one variable i tried below approach

```
from string import Template
s = Template(html123).safe_substitute(Var1=LockingVar)
```

If i have multiple variables

```
html123='''
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 300px;
  border: 15px solid green;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Demonstrating the Box Model</h2>

<div>This text is $Var1</div>
<div>This text is $Var2</div>
<div>This text is $Var3</div>

</body>
</html>
</html>   '''
```

but if we have multiple variables Var1,var2,var3 inside html tag , how can we map those variables values .

Please any suggestion..

Comment: Why can't you use your first solution multiple times?

Comment: @JeffUK .. You mean in this way """""" Template(html123).safe_substitute(Var1=LockingVar) ..safe_substitute(Var1=LockingVar)  """"" .. i tried but not working for multiple

Comment: would [`jinja`](https://palletsprojects.com/p/jinja/) be an option for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide a dict to safe_substitute

```
>>> params = {
...  'Var1':'aa',
...  'Var2':'bb',
...  'Var3':'cc'
... }

>>> Template("$Var1 $Var2 $Var3").safe_substitute(params)  
"aa bb cc"
```